# Geometry topics in physics

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra

I'd like to learn modern physics at an advanced level, but since I've no access to university, I'm self-teaching, and appeal to the Internet for information about what to study and how.

Currently, I'm trying to form a strong mathematical background. Until now, I've studied basic Linear Algebra and Affine/Euclidean/Projective geometry (in a linear algebra approach), because these are the first topics studied by Physics undergraduates in my country (Italy). But since I've virtually no time limit, instead of progressing to Real Analysis, I'd like to deepen the knowledge of what I've already studied.

What are according to you, of the topics I've listed, the most important for Physics, or the most important for future geometrical studies (which, I suppose, should be differential/algebraic geometry, topology...)?

Thank you for any answer!

Comment: The obvious answer is general relativity and gauge theories.

Comment: That is differential geometry of smooth and riemanninan manifolds and fiber bundles. Symplectic manifolds would not hurt too.

Comment: Differential (Riemannian and symplectic) geometry is of basical importance to study general relativity and dynamical systems; differential geometry in connection with Lie groups and algebras (and their representations) will be helpful to understand the role of symmetries in physics. A good knowledge of topological, metric, normed and Hilbert spaces (maybe these topics are not so geometric, but it depends on your taste) is crucial to understand Quantum mechanics.

Comment: Also functional analysis is an infinite-dimensional generalisation of linear algebra, but it takes strong background in calculus/analysis. It is important in PDEs and quantum physics. PS Somewhat overlaps with __yuggib__ remark.

Comment: Thank you for your illustrations, but I was not asking about what I should study next (I can get the information on the website of some universities), or which physical theories require geometry, instead, among l. algebra, affine, euclidean and projective geometry, which is worth of getting a deeper study

Comment: Everything may or may not deserve a deeper study; it depends what you need the knowledge for. The program of math courses for physicists of italian universities is ***the minimum necessary knowledge*** a general physicist must have on these topics, in order to understand physics (at a graduate level); however it may not be sufficient for a specialist. Since you are an high school student, if you think you know these subjects at the level of an undergrad physics exam, it is already enough, and you can focus on something else.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start studying something else, and maybe get back to basic geometry as soon as I realize I need it

Comment: Look for the book "geometry, topology and physics" by Mikio Nakahara. It is formal, but not too much. very nice book. Google it, the entire pdf is online.

Comment: Sorry Nicol, for me "the deeper study of geometry" sound like switching from simplest areas (like lin. algebra, affine, Euclidean and projective geometries) to more advanced ones. Deeper study of these same areas is either hardly possible (at high school level), or implies return to them after studying advanced topics, to review from another perspective. So when you finished one textbook, there is usually no point in making no headway.